# Exec() read from file

Tags: c++, exec, dup2

I am working on creating a basic shell. I'm stuck on trying to get exec() to read in from an input file. Here's what I have. I'm unsure what arguments I should be feeding execvp(). Here, stringList[0] will be something along the lines of "ls" or "cat". If stringList[0] is ls the file would contain something along the lines of ls -a -l

```
int fd = open(iFile, O_RDONLY);
dup2(fd, 0);
close(fd);

execvp(stringList[0], ...);
cout << "Exec error!\n";
exit(1);
```

Comment: Have you checked the return values of `open` and `dup2`? It's not only `execvp` that may fail.

Comment: *I'm stuck on trying to get exec() to read in from an input file.* What do you expect to find in the file and how do you wish to use the contents of the file?

Comment: If stringList[0] was ls then the file would contain something along the lines of ls -a -l

Comment: http://linux.die.net/man/3/execvp clearly shows: `int execvp(const char *file, char *const argv[]);`, so next to `cat`, put all parameters in an array of c-style strings and pass that.  If you have an input string for `cat`, put that in the array, together with possible command options. Not an answer, because it is mainly a link and some attempt on answering.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to read a command from a file and then execute that command. If that's your objective, you should actually be executing *the shell*.

Your current approach of `open` then `dup2` doesn't cause `exec` to read from a file, because `exec` never reads from standard input. It only reads from the executable (to load the program image). What your current approach does is *redirect* input, so that if `exec` is successful, the new program will have `iFile` as its standard input file.

You can just do this:

```
execl(shell, basename(shell), iFile, (char*)0);
```

Example: if `iFile` is the string `"myCommand.sh"`, and `shell` is `/bin/bash`, then `basename(shell)` gives `bash`, and this is similar to running this on the command line:

```
$ bash myCommand.sh
```

For `shell` you probably want to use the current user's default shell. You can obtain this information portably using `getpwuid` or `getpwuid_r`.